# Unwanted table data with changing with JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a table in which PHP is used in `<td>` tags. This contains a list of products and their prices. On the top of the table, I have inserted two buttons, one for arranging data in ascending order of price, and the other one is for descending order.

By default, the data is in ascending order. When I click on the descending order button, it works but with of the table data changes which is not required.

Here is my CSS code:

```
a {text-decoration:none; color:#0000FF;}
#hold .log {
  color:#0000FF;
   text-align:center;
   font-size:20px;
}

h2 {color:#0000FF;}
#left { width:200px;border:1px;border-style:solid;margin:0 auto;margin-top:20px;text-align:center;border-    color:#0000FF;float:left;}
#left div {border:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#0000FF;}
#left div a {}
.style table {border:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#0000FF;}
.style table tr td {border:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#0000FF;color:#333;width:250px;}
.style table tr td input,select,textarea {width:250px;height:30px;}
```

Here is the code for the table:

```
<button onclick="as()">Ascending Order</button>
<button onclick="ds()">Descding Order</button>

<div class="style">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Title</td>
    <td>Price</td>
</tr>
<th><h2 style="text-align:left;">Cameras</h2></th>
<tr>    
  <?php $i=1;
        $qry_cam=mysql_query("SELECT* FROM camera ORDER BY camera.price ASC",$con);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry_cam))
        {
          echo "<tr id='cam_as'>
                  <td>$i-$row[title]<br /></td>
                  <td>$row[price]<br /></td>
                </tr>";
          $i++;
        }
  ?>
</tr>
<tr>    
  <?php $i=1;
        $qry_cam=mysql_query("SELECT* FROM camera ORDER BY camera.price DESC",$con);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry_cam))
        {
          echo "<tr id='cam_ds' style='display:none;'>
                  <td>$i-$row[title]<br /></td>
                  <td>$row[price]<br /></td>
                </tr>";
          $i++;
        }
  ?>

</tr>
</table>
</div><!-- style ends-->
```

Finally, here is the script which is doing this all required work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function as()
  {
    $('#cam_as,#com_as,#cell_as').css('display','block');
    $('#cam_ds,#com_ds,#cell_ds').css('display','none');    
  }

  function ds()
  {
    $('#cam_ds,#com_ds,#cell_ds').css('display','block');
    $('#cam_as,#com_as,#cell_as').css('display','none');
  }

</script>
```

I have tried but I am unable to find where I am going wrong.

Comment: You have <tr> inside another <tr> in your code. And you also writing many <tr>'s with same **id**'s which is wrong - use classes instead.

Comment: Also consider using javascript-based sorting instead of getting same data from database two times - for example http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

Comment: as far as i know, i id is used for only one element and i am doing the same thing....still i tried replacing id's with classes but the error is the same...also for  <tr>'s, i was first using single <tr> but the problem was the sames...so there must be some other mistake...

Comment: I don't see `com_ds,cell_ds,com_as,cell_as`. where did you use them?

Comment: @Amir these id's can be used outside this snippet - Jquery will ignore them (didn't raise any errors) if they will not be present on the page.

Comment: @AwaisUmar, sorry, but i could not get the problem you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoo have enough problems with your code. I removed extra < tr >'s. I added classes and changed javascript functions accordingly. Your  problem is mainly in nested < tr >'s

http://jsfiddle.net/Sanya_Zol/kC9Tk/

```
<button onclick="as()">Ascending Order</button>
<button onclick="ds()">Descding Order</button>

<div class="style">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Title</td>
    <td>Price</td>
</tr>
<th><h2 style="text-align:left;">Cameras</h2></th>

<?php $i=1;
    $qry_cam=mysql_query("SELECT* FROM camera ORDER BY camera.price ASC",$con);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry_cam))
    {
      echo "<tr class='cam_as'>
              <td>$i-$row[title]<br /></td>
              <td>$row[price]<br /></td>
            </tr>";
      $i++;
    }
?>

<?php $i=1;
    $qry_cam=mysql_query("SELECT* FROM camera ORDER BY camera.price DESC",$con);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry_cam))
    {
      echo "<tr class='cam_ds' style='display:none;'>
              <td>$i-$row[title]<br /></td>
              <td>$row[price]<br /></td>
            </tr>";
      $i++;
    }
?>

</table>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function as(){
    $('.cam_as,#com_as,#cell_as').show();
    $('.cam_ds,#com_ds,#cell_ds').hide();
}

function ds(){
    $('.cam_ds,#com_ds,#cell_ds').show();
    $('.cam_as,#com_as,#cell_as').hide();
}
$(as); // run as() when document ready
</script>
```

Comment: Hat's off to you...thanks :-)
but what is the problem in using nested <tr>'s ?
i have used them just like we can us a <ul> inside another <li> and the same is for <li> in another <li>.....

Answer (score 0):

There are `<tr>`Tag outside and inside the loop, you only need them one time.
The loop would also create multiple `<tr>` Tags with the same ID, thats not correct. Try to use [jQuery-Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to show/hide the elements.

The last part of the question is not clear for me, sorry.